# SQL - SELECT in string WHERE LIKE word1,word2,etc

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a issu with my sql query.
For each id in MySQL there is 1 or multiple tags.
For example, id 1 have in his tags columns "110,2,3".
id 2 have "3,1100". etc...
Each number in tags string is a group.
I need to SELECT users from specific group.

So I tried to use LIKE operator in SQL:

```
$query = $db->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE taglist LIKE :id_groups OR :id_groups2 OR :id_groups3"
    );

$query->execute([
  "id_groups"=> $id_groups.",%",
  "id_groups3"=> "%,".$id_groups,
  "id_groups2"=> "%,".$id_groups.",%"
  ]);
```

But isn't working as i wish. For example, if I replace $id_groups by "3", with the upper example. That will only SELECT the id 2, and not the id 1 even if id 1 have "3" in its tags.

And the last issu is how can i do when there is only 1 number in the string ?
If I add another OR with "id_groups4"=> $id_groups that return me all the users even if they aren't in this group.

Comment: Do you have the option to redesign your tables? Because that's the best answer here. Your tags should probably be in a 1:N relationship in their own table so you don't have to parse the data like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a field with every OR:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE taglist LIKE :id_groups OR taglist LIKE :id_groups2 OR taglist LIKE :id_groups3");

$query->execute([
  "id_groups"=> $id_groups.",%",
  "id_groups3"=> "%,".$id_groups,
  "id_groups2"=> "%,".$id_groups.",%"
  ]);
```

Note this use case doesn't cover a single tag as this expects every tag to be preceded or followed by a comma, you really need:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE taglist = :id_groups OR taglist LIKE :id_groups1 OR taglist LIKE :id_groups2 OR taglist LIKE :id_groups3");

$query->execute([
  "id_groups"=> $id_groups,
  "id_groups1"=> $id_groups.",%",
  "id_groups3"=> "%,".$id_groups,
  "id_groups2"=> "%,".$id_groups.",%"
  ]);
```